# error in after magento 2 footer

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, magento2.3.4

I am getting text like  Method, Total (ms),Average (ms),Count in footer when I change website mode developer to production mode. Can someone help me with this? How can I resolve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to disable the profiler - `bin/magento dev:profiler:disable`
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html#cli

Comment: not working. i don't think it is any thing do with profiler. it something related with cache.